# Duplicate in list keeps first element

Tags: python, list

I can't understand why the result shows 2 'red'. The result is: [red, pink, red, white, blue]

```
string ='red,red,white,white,pink,blue,red,white,blue'
wordlist = string.split(',')
for i in wordlist:
   if (wordlist.count(i) > 1):
      wordlist.remove(i)
print(wordlist)
```

Comment: You are modifying the list while you are iterating over it. Just pass it through a set: `list(set(s.split(',')))`

Comment: but i dont want to use set function

Comment: what s the mistake exactly here can u pls explain?

Comment: When you are on the first element, you find element `red` is duplicated. So you delete it. Now you go to element 2. That's now `white` because the list now starts `['red', 'white'...]` — you skip the second red. Try adding `print(wordlist, i)` as the first line of the for loop to see what's happening.

Comment: To add on to what @MarkMeyer said, when get to `blue`, it removes it then moves to the next index which is `white` because the entire list is shifted over 1 after the removal resulting in the program skipping the last `red`.

Comment: Can you explain further why you don't want to use `set`?

Answer (score 0):

The function `remove()` just removes the first occurrence found. You have the word 'red' 3 times in your list. So just the first one is removed, remaining 2.
A possible solution is:

```
for i in wordlist:
    while wordlist.count(i)>1:
    wordlist.remove(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

U can use `fromkeys()` function to remove the duplicate list.

```
string ='red,red,white,white,pink,blue,red,white,blue'
wordlist = string.split(',')
wordlist = list(dict.fromkeys(wordlist))
print(wordlist)
```

output : `['red', 'white', 'pink', 'blue']`